# How to get list of records from matching two DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, matplotlib, pyspark

I am developing PySpark script for a project.
I have input dataframe like this:

```
+---+---------+
| id|direction|
+---+---------+
|  2|       up|
|  3|       up|
|  4|     down|
|  5|       up|
|  6|     down|
|  7|     down|
+---+---------+
```

And my processed dataframe is:

```
+----+---+---------+-----+
| day| id|direction|count|
+----+---+---------+-----+
|day1|  1|       up|   10|
|day1|  2|       up|   40|
|day1|  3|       up|   42|
|day1|  4|     down|   39|
|day1|  5|       up|   55|
|day1|  6|     down|   43|
|day1|  7|     down|   41|
|day2|  1|     down|   39|
|day2|  2|       up|   44|
|day2|  3|       up|   50|
|day2|  4|     down|   43|
|day2|  5|     down|   34|
|day2|  6|     down|   30|
|day2|  7|       up|   23|
|day3|  1|     down|   20|
|day3|  2|       up|   25|
|day3|  3|       up|   33|
|day3|  4|       up|   41|
|day3|  5|       up|   55|
|day3|  6|     down|   33|
|day3|  7|     down|   23|
|day4|  1|       up|   45|
|day4|  2|       up|   56|
|day4|  3|       up|   60|
|day4|  4|     down|   49|
|day4|  5|       up|   61|
|day4|  6|     down|   53|
|day4|  7|     down|   40|
|day5|  1|       up|   20|
|day5|  2|       up|   30|
|day5|  3|       up|   37|
|day5|  4|     down|   19|
|day5|  5|       up|   25|
|day5|  6|     down|   23|
|day5|  7|     down|   18|
|day6|  1|       up|   11|
|day6|  2|     down|    9|
|day6|  3|     down|    8|
|day6|  4|     down|    6|
|day6|  5|       up|   23|
|day6|  6|       up|   29|
|day6|  7|       up|   34|
+----+---+---------+-----+
```

I want to plot a graph of days that match with my input dataframe record. 
like here, `day1, day4, day5` matched with the input dataframe.
So, my final output would be 3 line graphs indicating day 1,4, and 5. with `x-axis as id` and `y-axis as count`.

I used `groupBy()` and `join()` function but it will not give me the exact result.
I also unsure about how to plot dataframe result. Do I have to convert it to `list` like structure first?

**EDIT: I have created temp dataframes that contains few rows:**

```
df_input = spark.createDataFrame({
    (2, 'up', ),
    (3, 'up', ),
    (4, 'down', ),
    (5, 'up', ),
    (6, 'down', ),
    (7, 'down', )
}, ['id', 'direction'])

df_input.sort('id').show()

df_proccsed_table = spark.createDataFrame({
    ('day1', 1, 'up', 10, ),
    ('day1', 2, 'up', 40, ),
    ('day1', 3, 'up', 42, ),
    ('day1', 4, 'down', 39, ),
    ('day1', 5, 'up', 55, ),
    ('day1', 6, 'down', 43, ),
    ('day1', 7, 'down', 41, ),
    ('day2', 1, 'down', 39, ),
    ('day2', 2, 'up', 44),
    ('day2', 3, 'up', 50),
    ('day2', 4, 'down', 43),
    ('day2', 5, 'down', 34),
    ('day2', 6, 'down', 30),
    ('day2', 7, 'up', 23),
    ('day3', 1, 'down', 20),
    ('day3', 2, 'up', 25),
    ('day3', 3, 'up', 33),
    ('day3', 4, 'up', 41),
    ('day3', 5, 'up', 55),
    ('day3', 6, 'down', 33),
    ('day3', 7, 'down', 23),
    ('day4', 1, 'up', 45),
    ('day4', 2, 'up', 56),
    ('day4', 3, 'up', 60),
    ('day4', 4, 'down', 49),
    ('day4', 5, 'up', 61),
    ('day4', 6, 'down', 53),
    ('day4', 7, 'down', 40),
    ('day5', 1, 'up', 20),
    ('day5', 2, 'up', 30),
    ('day5', 3, 'up', 37),
    ('day5', 4, 'down', 19),
    ('day5', 5, 'up', 25),
    ('day5', 6, 'down', 23),
    ('day5', 7, 'down', 18),
    ('day6', 1, 'up', 11),
    ('day6', 2, 'down', 9),
    ('day6', 3, 'down', 8),
    ('day6', 4, 'down', 6),
    ('day6', 5, 'up', 23),
    ('day6', 6, 'up', 29),
    ('day6', 7, 'up', 34),
}, ['day', 'id', 'direction', 'count'])
    
df_proccsed_table.sort('day', 'id').show(100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left join, and compare the number of non-null rows in each group of `id` to the number of rows in `df_input` in order to decide whether the pattern matches fully.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

filtered = df_proccsed_table.join(
    df_input.toDF('id2', 'direction2'),
    F.expr('id = id2 and direction = direction2'),
    'left'
).withColumn(
    'match',
    F.expr(f'count(id2) over(partition by day) = {df_input.count()}')
).filter('match').drop('match', 'id2', 'direction2').sort('day', 'id')

filtered.show(999)
+----+---+---------+-----+
| day| id|direction|count|
+----+---+---------+-----+
|day1|  1|       up|   10|
|day1|  2|       up|   40|
|day1|  3|       up|   42|
|day1|  4|     down|   39|
|day1|  5|       up|   55|
|day1|  6|     down|   43|
|day1|  7|     down|   41|
|day4|  1|       up|   45|
|day4|  2|       up|   56|
|day4|  3|       up|   60|
|day4|  4|     down|   49|
|day4|  5|       up|   61|
|day4|  6|     down|   53|
|day4|  7|     down|   40|
|day5|  1|       up|   20|
|day5|  2|       up|   30|
|day5|  3|       up|   37|
|day5|  4|     down|   19|
|day5|  5|       up|   25|
|day5|  6|     down|   23|
|day5|  7|     down|   18|
+----+---+---------+-----+
```

To plot the results:

```
pdf = filtered.toPandas()
pdf.set_index('id').groupby('day')['count'].plot(legend=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how `match` column results build up? means what inside `expr` code do?

Comment: @VivekChaudhari `match` is a boolean column, which specifies whether the count of non-null `id2` in each group of day is equal to the count of rows in `df_input`. If that is true, it means the whole pattern in `df_input` is matched.